# How do I make an __eq__method to compare a class with 4 init variables?

Tags: python, class, equality

I have the following class:

```
class Building():
   def __init__(self, item1, item2, item3, item4):
       self._item1 = item1
       self._item2 = item2
       self._item3 = []
       self._item3.append(item3)
       self._item4 = []
       self._item4.append(item4)

  def __eq__(self, building2):
```

Item1 and item2 are both int values, item3 and item4 are both lists that contain 1 item at the start with more added later possibly. How do I compare two building classes such that building1 == building2 would return true or false.

Edit: thanks for the feedback everyone, I have taken what everyone has said and changed my code it is much better now thanks!

Comment: What’s the rule here? Is it just two buildings are equal if their item1, item2, item3, and item4 are all equal? If so, just write that: `return self._item1 == building2._item1 and self._item2…`.

Comment: Why don't you rename `item3` and `item4` lists to something like `item3_list` and so on?

Comment: Perhaps `[item3]` is more concise than append?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate two tuples and compare them:

```
def __eq__(self, building2):
    return (self._item1, self._item2, self._item3, self._item4) == (
        building2._item1, building2._item2, building3._item1, building4._item1)
```

Comment: Does this compare the lists to check that list1[0] == list2[0] and so on since the order matters as well for the items in the list

Answer (score 2):

You can build tuples of those attributes that you want to compare, then compare those tuples.  Make sure to check if the other object is actually a `Building` to avoid raising an `AttributeError`

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Building):
        return False
    self_attrs = (self._item1, self._item2, self._item3, self._item4)
    other_attrs = (other._item1, other._item2, other._item3, other._item4)
    return self_attrs == other_attrs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __eq__(self, building2):
  result1 = self.item1 == building2.item1
  result2 = self.item2 == building2.item2
  result3 = self.item3[0] == building2.item3[0]
  result4 = self.item4[0] == building2.item4[0]
  return result1 and result2 and result3 and result4
```

Comment: Why compare just first elements, not entire lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute `_items` in your `__init__` with

```
self._items = self._item1, self._item2, self._item3, self._item4
```

and then define `__eq__` as

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self._items == other._items
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin `vars()` to compare object's dictionaries:

```
class Building():
    def __init__(self, item1, item2, item3, item4):
        self._item1 = item1
        self._item2 = item2
        self._item3 = []
        self._item3.append(item3)
        self._item4 = []
        self._item4.append(item4)

    def __eq__(self, building2):
        if not isinstance(building2, Building):
            return False
        return vars(self) == vars(building2)

b1 = Building(1, 2, 3, 4)
b2 = Building(1, 2, 3, 4)
b3 = Building(1, 2, 3, 3)
print(b1 == b2)
print(b1 == b3)
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

in **eq** you should use type(self) == type(other) instead of isinstance(other, self_class_name):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (type(self), vars(self)) == (type(other), vars(other))
```

Try to run:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name='Guido', surname='van Rossum'):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

class Student(Person):
    __slots__ = 'university'
    def __init__(self, university='University of Amsterdam',**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.university = university

p = Person()
s = Student()
print(isinstance(s, Person))
print(vars(p) == vars(s))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation on why your answer is different or works better than other answers? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer